# Can meta-style 'required tags' be implemented on non-meta sites?

Tags: support, tags, required-tags

> **Disclaimer:** This is a [support](/questions/tagged/support) question solely to see if such a feature exists, and not a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to ask for its implementation. If possible, I'd love it if we could focus on whether the feature exists rather than whether it would be useful or not.

On meta, each question must be tagged with one of the following:

- [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion)
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)
- [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)
- [support](/questions/tagged/support)

Is there a way to implement the same functionality on a non-meta site if the community requests it? For instance, if there were a Microsoft Office Stack Exchange site, is it possible to require each question to contain either:

- [word](/questions/tagged/word)
- [excel](/questions/tagged/excel)
- [powerpoint](/questions/tagged/powerpoint)
- [outlook-entourage](/questions/tagged/outlook-entourage)
- [onenote](/questions/tagged/onenote)
- [access](/questions/tagged/access)
- [infopath](/questions/tagged/infopath)
- [publisher](/questions/tagged/publisher)
- etc.

I searched the meta but couldn't find an answer. Perhaps some friendly savant can help me out?

Comment: I'm sure it could if you could come up with a set of tags that will cover 100% of your on-topic questions.  Do you have a specific site in mind?

Comment: Yes, [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) covers, well, the Workplace, and in general three things: (1) questions involving the hiring process (2) questions involving leaving a job (3) questions involved with your current job. Currently there are over 200 tags all over the place, and while we are working on cleaning them up, they would likely get messy again in a hurry without some attempt to categorize them.

Comment: Let's make the [bitcoin] tag required on [bitcoin.se]

Comment: @jmac those are idea... are there tags for those topics?

Comment: @psubsee2003 No, currently there aren't tags for those topics. There are tags for components of the topics, but since we have 200 tags (and you need at least 5 reputation in a tag to make synonym suggestions), not to mention that it only takes 150 reputation to recommend new tags, even if we did create them it wouldn't help out much. [See this meta workplace post](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/general-tag-classification-categorizing-the-madness) to understand my thought process.

Answer (score 5):

I do not believe the Stack Exchange team has ever commented on whether or not the required tags feature exists on non-meta sites. *However*, based on what I do know of how the platform works, it is very probable that it is simply a configuration parameter and can be enabled very easily by the SE team if they wished to (whether you will be able to persuade them is quite another matter, and I should warn you that I think it unlikely that you would succeed).

Comment: Why do you think it will be unlikely? Is there some discussion of this somewhere that I'm missing? @psubsee seems to share the same concern, but I haven't figured out where the opposition to the concept is coming from. Was there some discussion about the role of tags from on high that I missed?

Comment: @jmac Intuition and experience. Main sites do not generally fall into clear question divisions; if such divisions do exist, there's an argument to be made that the site was poorly defined to exist. Sites should exist more as a continuum of topic.

Comment: There is a clear definition of what is in Microsoft Office, and if on-topic is defined as "questions related to microsoft-office" then any question should be clearly asking about one (or more) of those programs, no? Or would this be a poorly defined site because each of the MS Office apps should have its own SE?

Comment: @jmac Well, in this case, [su] is a superset of all questions that would be permitted on the Office site. Does this mean that if [su] didn't exist, Office would be a bad site? Not necessarily, but when you hit something like this, you want to check if either going broader or narrower will bring a better site. Now, hypothetically speaking, if we were to have an Office site, I could imagine questions about the suite but not about any of the Office apps in particular. Sure, we could create a tag for the suite, but it's often hard to know exactly what questions you're going to get ahead of time.

Comment: I also don't want to suggest that there are *absolutely no sites* on which this might not make sense, but the point I am trying to get at is that in the vast majority of cases, this is a warning sign that the site might not be successful, because instead of having one homogenous audience, you now have X different audiences all on one site. Again, not necessarily always the case, but it is something that I think the SE team would be worried about.

Comment: Maybe I'm approaching this from the wrong angle, but I see a site with a clear topic (or set of topics) where the tags aren't working to actually categorize things in a way that make them more accessible. While that may mean that we should be working hard to recategorize everything, there is a point (200 tags, 5000 applications of those tags) where the amount of knowledge to properly do that work becomes oppressively difficult even with a lot of effort. Since there is no 'common sense' classification when it comes to questions involving the Workplace, it becomes a much different task.

Comment: Let's say I am having an issue where my company is being bought out and my position has become redundant. Should this be tagged [acquisition]? Perhaps [redundancy]? [layoff]? [severance]? All of the above? But what if there is a similar question that provides the needed information but applies to someone else's experience with bankruptcy of their company. That wouldn't share any of the above tags, but yet be distinctly related. Yet someone in that situation is unlikely to pick a tag that says [leaving-job] or something of the sort because they are focused on their specific details.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you need to force users to fit their question into a tag?  Isn't it possible someone could come up with a question that is on topic (or at least sort of on-topic) that doesn't fit neatly into one of your tags?  Are you going to expect them to fit a round peg into a square hole?

And what if the scope of the site changes, are you going to change the require tags?  That opens up another set of issues because now if someone tries to edit an old question that doesn't have one of the current required tags, the edit will be blocked until they add a current required tag.

On meta sites, the required tags work because the required tags are general enough to fit every question.  But on non-meta sites, tags are supposed to be specific and describe the question.  Are you virtually certain you can come up with a set of tags that will cover 100% of every possible on topic question forever and ever?

If you can come up with a set of tags that can always be applicable, I'm sure the required tag idea can be implemented since the functionality exists in the code-base, but I think you need to come up with a strong reason, have the tags ready, with good wikis and have very strong community support.

The meta.Workplace.SE [question](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2009/general-tag-classification-categorizing-the-madness) you mention in your comments does seem to provide a foundation for a solid tag structure idea, the idea of a site topic changing still is an issue.

Programmers.SE might be a bit of an extreme example, but it was originally conceived of as a site for programming questions that didn't fit into SO's narrow scope, but when that was determined to be a failure, the scope was adjusted.  So if they had required tags originally, and old question would be forced to use a new required tag if edited.

If you come up with your set of tags, but at some point in the future, a new topic is made on-topic and an existing one is removed, what are you going to do with the old questions that have the now no longer required tag?  If you keep them, and someone tries to edit them, they will get an error, similar to how users get errors trying to edit old questions with "Problem" in the title since it is now a blacklisted word.

Comment: With a site as subjective as the Workplace, one of the challenges is what to tag things for people asking questions. Our third most popular tag is [professionalism](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/professionalism) which is a catch-all for a bunch of different questions. Our second most popular tag is [software-industry](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-industry) which is mostly non-industry-specific questions. Identifying questions by a state-tag (where they are in the process) would help make tags more relevant to finding/answering questions

Comment: If you are looking for a new job, and want to know what to ask your new manager to determine working environment, do you tag that management? Do you tag it interviewing? Do you tag it work-environment? All would be reasonable (they all apply), but universally this question would fall under 'finding-employment' or a similar tag that encompasses the entire process of finding (or hiring for) a job.

Comment: @jmac I'm not saying it is a bad idea, and I can understand selecting approrpaite tags is confusing for new users who don't know the site, but setting required tags might be more trouble than it is worth in the long term.  Community moderation is supposed to help with the issues you mentioned by cleaning up and retagging questions, but if that isn't happening, maybe that is the issue and not the tag system.

Comment: The main question is if the functionality already exists. Since it exists on meta, I am wondering if it's just a simple switch someone has to throw to enable for a site. If so, whether 'it is more trouble than it's worth' could be decided by the community (rather than by a feature-request. If not, then it's a much more complicated discussion. My goal here is just to find out if the functionality already exists to help decide how to proceed.

Comment: @jmac as waiwai mentions, I do believe it is a simple switch for the same reason as he does - it exists in the code-base so it should be possible to turn it on.  Maybe Shog or Anna or a dev will stop by eventually and confirm

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the feature exists, but it's not mentioned as something that can be customized. This was already mentioned in the previous answers [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195199/1359324), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195189/1359324). Still, there is something that was not mentioned earlier, and I just realized:

The "need" to use required tags is a symptom of an underlying problem related to the scope and site moderation done by the community.

Some possible "root" causes:

- The site scope is too broad.
  One example is Super Users and "Programmers" (nowadays Software Engineering).  Super Users gradually banned specific "subtopics" like web applications, which motivated the Web Applications Stack Exchange Area 51 proposal. There is a comment from Robert Cartaino affirming this.
- The site audience is too diverse.
  The rules, policies and standards are too broad/loose to allow anyone to participate.
- There is no core community.
  A core community leads with its example and helps new users to learn the community rules, policies and standards. Without this leadership, the community might get any questions that might be hard to be handled using tags.
- There is no consensus about the site scope, rules, policies and standards.
  The community might be facing a wicked problem or suffering from groupthink. The "consensus" might is to keep all community members happy despite that deviates the community from its purpose and the Stack Overflow premises.

---

Things that were announced that can be customized are

- Design: [Responsive Design Themes - What can sites customize and how can they get changes implemented?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/1359324)
- Ask Question form: [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/1359324)
- Settings like the number of questions that are bumped each hour.
- Tag warnings
- Blocked words in question title and body
- Blocked tags
- Tour, Help Center homepage and help/how-to-ask
- Custom close reasons
- ...

Despite not being mentioned, that feature is used in Stack Apps. This is a particular site:

[image: Stack Apps]

##### Stack Apps

- It is a question-and-answer site like other Stack Exchange sites.
- It works as a site and a meta site, like Meta Stack Exchange and Area 51 Discussion Zone  (Area 51 DZ hasn't community moderators, only community managers).
- It has [required-tags](/questions/tagged/required-tags) like Meta Stack Exchange and [per-site-meta](/questions/tagged/per-site-meta)s: [bug](/questions/tagged/bug), [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) and [support](/questions/tagged/support).
- It has non standard tags : [app](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/app), [library](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library) and [script](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library)
- It also posts to register an application.

##### Related

###### From here

- [Add question classification on top of question tagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349967/1359324)

###### From per-site metas

- [Make the criteria tags obligatory](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1281)
- [Answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/807) to [Is there some way to force the user to indicate render engine in use?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/805)
- [Suggesting mandatory tags](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2195)