# Add question classification on top of question tagging

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, questions

Is it possible to add a question classification option? For example users who will be answering it may have preference for fixing issues (problem solving) vs how to build something (creativity). An analogy of question classification vs question tagging would be soft skills vs hard skills on your resume.

As an example please see image below from ZenDesk help desk system. For SO question classifications can be site specific or defined by moderators as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

I see no need to classify questions as being questions, incidents, problems, tasks or anything else.

Stack Exchange sites (in particular its Main sites) are **only for asking questions** (and getting answers to them).

If you are wanting to report, submit or discuss other things like incidents, problems, tasks or anything else, then your posts are likely to be closed for not asking a question.

Nevertheless, I do find that the best way to solve a problem is by asking a question, sometimes multiple separate questions, to help break it down.

Comment: Thank you. This request is to help users like me when selecting from a large number of questions which need answering on SO, whom it would benefit being able to filter questions by the question types they prefer. The image example above may not be relevant but it’s the best I could find. I understand if you may never need this feature.

Comment: @bestinamir  As Polygeo describes, anything in your proposed list which is not a “question”, should not appear on the site, so users filtering on any of the other options would just get no results.