# How do I as moderator of beta community change content of top right block on our Ask a Question page?

Tags: support, asking-questions

We are a community still in beta after many years. Long ago I created a block on the top right of our [Ask a Question page](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). How do I edit the content of that block as a moderator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, community moderators can't make these changes by themselves. You should post a feature request, get support from your community (upvotes, supporting comments and answers) and add the tag [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review). Don't add this tag if the request is unclear or lacks community support; this triggers something that apparently will require rework or might be "rejected".

The recommended request process is explained in [Catija's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377061/1395520) to [What site-specific changes can be made to the Ask Question page to help askers on that site write better questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/1395520).

Depending on the particular situation of your community, you might have to "test the waters" first either on the community chatroom or by posting a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion). This discussion might later be converted into a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) depending on the reactions / feedback received.

Here is a few examples

- Chemistry Meta: [Proposals for guidance presented to first-time askers](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5219)
- Code Review Meta: [Hide the "describe what you've tried" bullet (new askers' modal)](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10773)