# Can new users not be bait-and-switched?

Tags: feature-request, review, moderator-tools, new-users

As a new user on SE, I shared the common new-user experience of questions downvoted, and closed, and the feeling of being kicked around by (well-meaning) moderators, and perhaps worse, the suspicion of being manipulated (bullied?) by more experienced users who know how to push an agenda without raising moderator ire.

A quick look at Wikipedia reveals I'm not alone by a long shot:

> Trustpilot's page on Stack Overflow, the largest Stack Exchange, shows an average rating of 2.1 stars out of 5, a "Poor" rating. Although 28% of reviewers gave the site a good score, 69% of 136 reviewers gave the site a bad review of 2 stars or fewer. The website was accused by many users of having aggressive moderation that tended to exclude newcomers with lesser programming knowledge.

I'll spare you the vitriol of the Trustpilot reviews, but it ain't pretty.

There may be a good reason for the roughness, provided in many similar posts on Meta.SE ([e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users)): This is what it takes to prevent the site from being overrun with lousy content. That's a valid point.

On the other hand,
all this is clearly not good for sustained growth, and if another site figures out how to net untold new users they would squash us pretty quick.

Alternatively, if the issue is addressed properly it could launch SE to the stratosphere...

So, for what it’s worth, here's an analysis, then a suggestion, from the (in this case) valuable perspective of a newcomer.

### Why the bitter newcomers?

In my experience, the bad taste came from the *very welcoming tone of the site*, contrasted with the blunt-force trauma of being piled on as soon as the first question is posted.

For example, a newcomer sees this:

> Fill In the Blank Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for Filling in Blanks. It only takes a minute to sign up.
>
> Anybody can ask a question
>
> Anybody can answer
>
> The best answers are voted up and rise to the top

With all due respect, this is a bait-and-switch. Because the tone is so very welcoming (this seems like what I was looking for, let me ask my question!) compared to the actual new-user experience (owwww...). The unexpected shock leaves a sour taste, and it turns many potential users into angry Trustpilot warriors.

### What would have made it better?

**If nothing else, improve the language a new user sees.**

The US Navy SEALS don't say, "Anyone welcome!...Pow!" They make it clear it's tough to qualify. So a new user should be seeing things like "Anyone can ask a question, but **expect flak** till you're experienced!"

**Even better, however, would be the following:**

Let there be a New User Area (SE Bootcamp), where anyone new automatically goes first. There, posted questions are seen *only by other users/moderators who expressly volunteer as New User Trainees* (The Welcoming Committee). They commit to being friendly and looking to help. They provide the newcomer with suggestions, explanations, and welcomeness. At some point, the newcomer can request their question to be reviewed for release on the full site, at which point it can be voted on. After some threshold is met - of time, use, or successful question releases, the newcomer is cleared as a full user.

Hooray! No more bait-and-switch. No more nasty reviews. Everyone loves SE, new users soar, and content only *improves*. Unicorns are sighted above Alaska.

---

**Since this posted**, it seems from many comments/answers that the problem is known, and the fix is known - both by the company and the community. (This [company blog post from 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/07/18/building-community-inclusivity-stack-overflow/), and the comments on it by the community, brings it out nicely.) For some reason, the company has never moved on it in a real way - so don't blame the community.

Fair enough, with two follow-ups:

1. Was there ever any communication from the company as to WHY there's been no movement?
2. Isn't Meta SE the place to actually ask the company this question? (It would seem like it, because one of the tags is 'feature-request' - and who is that addressed at if not the company?)
   [For example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395384), on a recent feature-request:

> [image: comment]

So if company is silent, is that a way of saying, "Don't hold your breath?"

Comment: It is close to [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/staging-ground/info). Staging Ground is [on hold indefinitely](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427363/is-the-staging-ground-unofficially-abandoned) due to the AI craze. Hopefully, we will soon be way past the '[Peak of Inflated Expectations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gartner_hype_cycle#Five_phases)' and deep in the 'Trough of Disillusionment'.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum  The difference between "on hold indefinitely" and "cancelled" is sometimes difficult to discern.

Comment: "*..all this is clearly not good for sustained growth*" That's debatable. I think one of the greatest assets of the network is that it has a higher quality standard (in that regard) than most other even somewhat comparable sites, and I assume this is what keeps people visiting and participating—a large cause for bad user experience is that this is simply not true for everybody.

Comment: This has been [posted about before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342788/377214).

Comment: Relatable experience. I'm way past this point now, so much that I don't really contribute to this platform anymore (except for a few comments here and there, chat, and when it gets really interesting, for whatever reason). This is the same experience I had as a new user, before SE really took a nose dive into "the welcoming initiative". The problem seriously does lie in the way the site is presented, and the way new users are thought. SE won't fix this issue (they'd have done it long ago if they cared sufficiently), but it's worth to take note for future Q/A sites that seek to do better.

Comment: There's a serious cultural gap exemplified even in this question. New users typically expect to be able to go in blind and have experienced users tell them what they need to do. Meanwhile experienced users really want new users to learn at least some of the rules by themselves before posting. It's exhausting to have to guide every single user so it really is helpful if they take on some of the work themselves. Unfortunately the site design tends to make that hard, since the rules are usually hidden away.

Comment: Not sure why semi-anonymous feedback from a biased self-selecting sample is being taken as good evidence. How many people ever care enough to post positive or neutral reviews about their experience on the network, instead of just using it?

Comment: Of course, on the flip side, I think it would be helpful if experienced users recognized more of the frustrations of new users and tried to apply the rules consistently. Additionally, there's a limit to how much effort a new user can be expected to spend on a question, which should be kept in mind.

Comment: @Laurel, well said, and what do you expect from new users? They see an inviting forum with almost no warnings or guidelines unless they start digging and following links etc., but without better messaging you're guaranteed to have tons of people keep missing it, and keep exhausting experienced users. Clearer messaging would go a long way to make everyone's lives easier.

Comment: @AMtwo its the same thing as long as there's a disconnect between the goals of the company, the goals of the community, and what needs to be done to achieve either.

Comment: @YouDontSay The community is not the same as the SE company. We have different goals. There's a lot of frustration in the community because SE isn't being helpful. They have designed the site in a way orthogonal to what we need. So a lot of the anger should be directed towards SE, not the community. It's hard for us to do things right, when SE designed the site in a way that hampers our abilities, or goes against our goals. We expect users to educate themselves. We don't have the resources required to overcome the obstacles of the site design, so direct the criticism at SE, not us. :)

Comment: @Laurel, I think you hit the nail on the head. Software could better help guide new users through predictable/common onboarding tasks so that everyone has a better experience. The Staging Ground work (certainly the premise behind it) was really promising in that regard--in the old days, it was like having a "wizard" take you through a task versus the "Advanced setup."   I can only hope that it resurfaces as a priority sooner than later. Sadly, the 2023 staffing changes make me pessimistic about that.

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum, checked out Staging Ground, it is VERY close! That would be great. I guess until that sorts out, the only hope is to change the site wording...

Comment: @Nij, you do have a point there. Quora and Reddit don't fare much better on Trustpilot, although for different reasons.

Comment: It is bait & switch & that is a problem. But a Bootcamp is still a bait & switch. It just doesn't allow downvotes right away. It is effectively posting closed with votes blocked until opened or posting with votes blocked until allowed. (Depending on whether you want reviews or all users as readers.) It adds no other functionality. Anyway Bootcamp or other, the onus should not be on other users/curators to educate. (Except possibly a couple of worst-problem-with-this-post clicks.)

Answer (score 22):

> I'll spare you the vitriol of the Trustpilot reviews, but it ain't pretty.

Don't worry; everyone on the Meta sites is *acutely* aware of how SE, especially SO, is perceived off-site.

And yes, our reasons are more or less as you've understood them.

> On the other hand, all this is clearly not good for sustained growth, and if another site figures out how to net untold new users they would squash us pretty quick.

> Alternatively, if the issue is addressed properly it could launch SE to the stratosphere...

I am extremely doubtful on both points, for a variety of reasons.

But the main reason is that other sites are going to have an extremely difficult time "squashing" Stack Exchange, as long as we are counting Stack Overflow, on the basis of the sheer size of Stack Overflow. At least if they want to maintain an informative, quality-controlled, Q&A based format.

Stack Overflow has [just recently passed 24 million undeleted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions). To put that in perspective: for every **article on Wikipedia**, there are **more than three** Stack Overflow questions. (Or at least it was like that last I checked - and Wikipedia has been "dying" for longer than Stack Overflow has).

I would also like to point out here that while "sustained growth" might be a goal of the staff, it is not necessarily relevant to having a functional, high-quality Q&A site. Arguably, a Q&A site is **trying** to reach a state of **zero new questions and answers** - because it has already answered everything it is supposed to answer. Ideally, everyone who has a question that's suitable for the site (or can form such a question based on the underlying problem), can already find that Q&A and get a high-quality answer.

In fact, 24 million is probably way more questions than Stack Overflow needs for this purpose, considering what the average question quality looks like, how much junk turns up when trying to search for a canonical, how many duplicate questions are clearly not being recognized, etc.

Full disclosure: I am saying all of this as an active member and major proponent of ["another site"](https://codidact.com/).

> With all due respect, this is a bait-and-switch. Because the tone is so very welcoming

First off: I absolutely agree with you that the messaging could be better in general. We can't do anything about it, because we don't have rights to change it. It's under the control of the company, which has a vested interest in increasing participation rates. The company, evidently, does not think that "pre-screening" new users is any better than trying to advertise to them as hard as possible and letting them be disappointed later.

That said: Nothing in your quote is *incorrect*, and it would be *weird not to* emphasize that everyone is welcome to participate for a site that is open to the public and has a user-generated content (UGC) model - especially in today's political climate.

"The best answers rise to the top" does seem intended to evoke a spirit of competition. But more to the point, there's a lot more on these tour pages that's constantly being *ignored* in complaints like this one. Some choice quotes for you:

> we're working together to build a library of detailed answers

This is supposed to highlight the fact that questions don't exist simply for the benefit of the person asking.

> *We're a little bit different from other sites. Here's how:*

Pretty straightforward: new users **should not assume** that their ideas about participation norms from other UGC sites will carry over.

> This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat.

Yet we constantly receive new questions that include more information about OP than about the actual problem being asked about.

> Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are **primarily opinion-based**, or that are likely to **generate discussion** rather than answers.
>
> *Questions that need improvement may be closed until someone fixes them.*

Pretty straightforward, although it undersells the reality and only covers a few of the standard close reasons.

Moving on:

> So a new user should be seeing things like "Anyone can ask a question, but **expect flak** till you're experienced!"

There are *definitely* more positive, constructive ways to get the point across. Saying something like this would be explicitly setting up the expectation of conflict between new and experienced users, and **that dichotomy is false**.

You have *no idea* how many people I've run into on Stack Overflow with 10+ years of experience, to whom I've had to explain basic, fundamental ideas about how the site works. In many cases I've tried repeatedly with the same user and been ignored. (Especially when it's a matter of "please don't answer questions like this; the reason they get closed is specifically to prevent you from answering; you being so quick on the draw is bad for the quality of the site" etc.) On the other hand, new users absolutely do come in and ask good questions sometimes.

> Let there be a New User Area (SE Bootcamp)

Stack Overflow [tried this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/staging-ground). Interest from staff in supporting it [seems to have run out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427363/), despite that as far as I'm aware it was working well.

Comment: Re *"Interest from staff in supporting it seems to have run out"*: [This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395234) does not help either.

Comment: “At least if they want to maintain an informative, quality-controlled, Q&A based format.” – I doubt this part. I doubt those users care about it either; they just want answers to *their* questions, the wider knowledge base be damned. Not to say the character of the site is without its benefits, but it’s not like everyone appreciates them.

Comment: @user3840170 there are countless already existing sites that don't care about those things, sure. They also don't qualify as competition for Stack Exchange, because they are discussion forums. There are also plenty of "other sites" that do care about that kind of curation and about providing information in a UGC model *without* devolving into "answers to *their* questions". I already cited Codidact and Wikipedia (although Wikipedia isn't Q&A format, it also isn't a discussion forum and also doesn't tolerate selfish help-seeking behaviour).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, "Arguably, a Q&A site is trying to reach a state of zero new questions and answers - because it has already answered everything it is supposed to answer." Does this mean all the community-distancing actions of the company are justified because they have the answers they need already?

Answer (score 19):

I think one of the greatest assets of the network is that it has a higher quality standard (in that regard) than most other even somewhat comparable sites, and I assume this is what keeps most users visiting and participating—a large cause for bad user experience is that this is simply not the case for everybody.

I like how you framed your question: it is presented in a far more constructive and neutral way than many other similar questions, answers, and comments I have seen by disgruntled new users. So thank you for that.

But my reaction to your initially bad experience will be the same: inform yourself. There is already ample opportunity to do so. A big part of this is simply to look around; to read; to see how others behave, how things are done; and, perhaps ultimately most importantly, to communicate. If you don't know how something works or why something was done, *ask*. Nobody can fault you for that, and usually (on the sites I'm familiar with, at least) users will give constructive feedback. And, lastly, be willing to take criticism and adapt. More experienced users do usually know better (which doesn't mean they are always right).
It also always good to note that other users (including moderators) are real people, investing their time, effort, and patience voluntarily into this network.

In short: **anybody *can* ask a question, anybody *can* answer, but that doesn't mean *any*thing goes.  No bait-and-switch, just stating facts.**

Comment: thoughtful (and friendly!) answer. However expecting new users, who are invited so warmly to post their question, to train themselves in to all the nuance of the site before daring to post, is unrealistic unless it's somehow made clear in the first impression.

Comment: Lots of people come here thinking Stack Exchange is like a blend of Reddit and Quora, when it is not at all like either of those: SE has very high quality standards and no interest at all in discussions or primarily-personal opinion-based answers. As a result of their expectations, they don't fit in immediately, and a significant proportion are unable or unwilling to learn how to improve. Those that are here to learn and do make the effort, surprisingly don't complain about the welcome they received.

Comment: @Nij "Those that are here to learn and do make the effort, surprisingly don't complain about the welcome they received"; [Citation needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371115/what-if-i-dont-want-to-answer-but-still-want-to-help/371149#comment610963_371149). Huh. Times change. :D

Comment: "anybody can ask a question, anybody can answer, but that doesn't mean anything goes." Sounds a bit like the old line from Henry Ford, at a sales meeting... "Any customer can have a car painted any color that he wants so long as it is black."

Comment: @YouDontSay There are many shades of black, though :) I actually don't think those lines are anything alike. It's more like: you can park your car for free in our car park, but if it's really dirty, ugly, or rusted through, it will be slowly moved to a corner, and if it turns out it's actually a cardboard car, it will be removed.

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth, I agree that you've identified a problem. The banner (and the lack of much of anything to guide new users) creates a frustrating experience for everyone.

Pulling my comments into an answer:

There's a serious cultural gap exemplified here, even in the question itself. New users typically expect to be able to go in blind and have experienced users tell them what they need to do. Meanwhile experienced users really want new users to learn at least some of the rules by themselves before posting. It's exhausting to have to guide every single user so it really is helpful if they take on some of the work themselves. Unfortunately the site design tends to make that hard, since the rules are usually hidden away.

Of course, on the flip side, I think it would be helpful if experienced users recognized more of the frustrations of new users and tried to apply the rules consistently. Additionally, there's a limit to how much effort a new user can be expected to spend on a question, which should be kept in mind. But changing people is extremely hard, especially on the scale of Stack Overflow.

The "SE Bootcamp" you described arguably existed as the [Staging Ground](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/staging-ground/info) on SO. But it was shut down. I don't know all the details off the top of my head, and it doesn't matter. It requires development time, and nobody knows when that will happen. At this point, only extant features are worth spending time on.

There are some tools available to onboard users but they're extremely underused. I think few experienced users even know they exist, much less start discussions on setting them up. For example, the [Ask modal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377058/323179). Admittedly, the example shown in that question is pretty terrible—speaking as a moderator on that site (English Language and Usage). I want to replace it but I've been busy with other stuff ([the "flip side"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15694/191178)—the hard task of changing how experienced users act). There are also [tag warnings](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11865/191178) that can be set up, which is the only practical solution for guidance on many sites, including Stack Overflow where so much varies based on tag.

Where do we go from here? I don't really know. Someone needs to step forward and ask for changes like these.

Comment: I know this is subjective, but I rarely experienced how "*the rules are usually hidden away*", even at the beginning. True, they are not always *obvious*, but that's a different thing. I agree that onboarding can still be dramatically improved upon, but it really has to come from both directions.

Comment: @Joachim Without any customizations enabled on the site, you get the generic list of 3 items in the Ask modal and "Include all the information someone would need to answer your question" as a hint for the question body. None of this is worded really as a requirement. All the other information you'd have to go out of your way to find, some of it in places nobody new would ever think to look (this thing called a "meta").

Answer (score 11):

I see that you are downvoted, but I wanted to express my appreciation for your question.  I think it is helpful, constructive, and insightful.

In particular, I think you've got a good insight about the bait-and-switch.  I don't think that the introductory materials do a good job of expressing the mission of the site.  To be direct: We're not looking for stratospheric growth.  That is not our motivation -- at least, it's not the motivation of many users who participate here.  For many of us, our motivation is to build a high-quality archive of knowledge that will be useful to others in the future.  That's more important to many of us than growth for its own sake.

I agree with you that I don't think the introductory materials on the website do a good job of capturing that.  They do try to set a welcoming tone, which is welcome, but they don't emphasize the community's quality standards and the expectations we have for questions.

This is a sore point, that has been a point of contention between the company and some/many users who participate here.  My impression -- and it's just an impression, and could be wrong -- or maybe it is a fear -- is that the company places a higher priority on growth; whereas there are a group of users on the site who place a higher priority on quality.  The company controls the introductory materials.  Users on the site control voting and question closure.  So my impression is that the two have drifted apart a little bit, to the point where the introductory material does not perfectly align with the preferences and values of many users.

As for the solution, it's not clear how to solve this.  I think your specific proposals have some merits and some challenges, and we could dive into the details, but before we do that, I think it's good to acknowledge the problem, which I think you've accurately diagnosed.

---

I do want to push back on a few points.  We have heard from many newcomers who describe their experience as being "bullied", by "power-crazy moderators", etc.  I think that reflects a lack of understanding of the values, priorities, norms, and expectations on this site.  I don't think the issue is that moderators are "power-crazy".  I think the issue is that they are placing a higher priority on (their understanding of) the site's mission, than on the goals/needs of the individual newcomer who posted their question.

I recognize that it can be a difficult and frustrating experience.  I hope that gaining a deeper understanding of the motivation and values of others will help put your experience in a different light.